# how to recover deleted database from phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, backup

How can I retrieve the `phpMyAdmin database`.

currently I'm using a version of

here is the database server information

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 5.5.64-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Comment: phpMyaAdmin is not a database, is a tool for manipulating with mysql db.
If you delete some db form mysql you can not recover it with phpMyAdmin

Comment: No, I'm using MySQL using phpMyAdmin tool,
using this tool I lost my database (i deleted database)

Comment: I think you can not recover it with phpMyAdmin, try research `recover deleted db in mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Database is deleted is gone. It can only be recovered if you have stored a backup of it somewhere else.

Comment: Okay, Great I Understand very well. Nice.